# How to send data to the client and save it as a cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I know the basics of coding but I'm trying to understand API's, at the moment I'm trying to make an API that authorizes a user so I can see their information in a game.

Essentially I need to send data to my client from my server which is running Node.js and Express. I have managed to get the user authenticated but I then need to save that information as a cookie for later use.

The webapp starts on index.html and the API redirects the user back to auth.html.

**Server Side Code**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const {
  addAsync
} = require('@awaitjs/express');
const app = addAsync(express());
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const base64 = require('base-64');
const http = require('http');
// config libraries

const client_secret = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
// get env variables


function getCode(req) {
  var ru = url.format({
    protocol: req.protocol,
    host: req.get('host'),
    pathname: req.originalUrl
  });
  return ru.split("code=")[1];
}; // parse url to get auth code


const port = process.env.PORT || 4645;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
}); // set http server


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
}); // set '/' as index.html

app.getAsync('/auth', async (req, res) => {

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'auth.html'));

  const code = getCode(req);

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Basic ${base64.encode(`35544:${client_secret}`)}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: `grant_type=authorization_code&code=${code}`
  }

  const obj = await fetch('https://www.bungie.net/platform/app/oauth/token/', options); // response
  const data = await obj.json(); // json response = data

  console.log(data);

  // send json to client
  res.json(data);
  res.end();

});

app.get('/logout', async (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

**Client Side Code (index.html)**

```
<head>
    <script>

        // code
        

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    index.html <br>
    <a href='https://www.bungie.net/en/OAuth/Authorize?client_id=35544&response_type=code'>log in</a> <br>
</body>
```

**Client Side Code (auth.html)**

```
<head>
    <script>

        
        // catch json from server

        const options = {
            url: '/auth',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };

        fetch(options).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })

        

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    auth.html <br>
    <a href='/logout'>log out</a>
</body>
```

I know it's a lot but I hope someone can help me on this...

Thanks.

Edit:

I forgot to say that currently the client does not recieve the information at any point, and if it did i am unsure how to catch the response at the right time...

Thanks to everyone who already responded.

Comment: in your fetch response, use this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp You can also use localStorage instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without bothering to puzzle-out your code ... ***"never*** *trust the client."*

**Never** try to send the client any meaningful data as the content of a cookie.  The cookie's value should always be a perfectly-meaningless value – a *"nonce"* – which you can then refer to in order to look up anything you need to know from your server-side database. *"You can never trust the client-side."*